# Allow users from my ASP.Net MVC site to access my private WordPress site

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, single-sign-on

I have an ASP .Net MVC site and I would like users who are logged in to my site to be able to access a separate WordPress site which I also own. Otherwise, if a user is not logged into my ASP .Net site, the WordPress site should remain private.

What is the easiest way to implement this? I thought about SSO but it seems like overkill for this simple scenario. I don't need users identified on the WordPress site; they won't be allowed to post or anything, all they can do is just read my posts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the whole WP site private except to logged in users by using a plugin (Ultimate Member). Then I created a single login which would be used from the .Net site. The way it works is:

1. User clicks on link within .Net site to access WordPress site
2. Server-side: performs POST to /wp-login.php with credentials for single WP user
3. Server-side: retrieve cookies from wp-login.php response
4. Client-side: call to custom PHP page on WP site: /setcookies.php and set user’s session cookies for WP site domain using cookies from previous step
5. Client-side: open WP site in iframe using session cookies